# React component onClick handler not working

Tags: javascript, event-handling, reactjs

I have a basic pop-up (an image) that appears when you click on a button. When you click outside of that pop-up, it should close but when you click inside of it, it should stay open and call the test function. Its initial state, isPopupVisible, is set to false. When you click on the button, I set the state to true which renders the pop-up window.

The problem is the test function isn't being called when you click on the image. I think it is because the state is set to false and the image element with the onClick function isn't initially rendered. Does anyone know how to solve this?

(written in ecmascript 6)

```
getInitialState () {
  return {isPopupVisible: false}
},
onClick () {
  if(!this.state.isPopupVisible){
    this.setState({isPopupVisible: true});
    document.body.addEventListener('click', this.onClickBody)
  }
},
onClickBody () {
  this.setState({isPopupVisible: false});
  document.body.removeEventListener('click', this.onClickBody)
},
test () {
  console.log('the onClick from the image works!');
},
showPopup () {
  if(this.state.isPopupVisible){
    return <div>
      <img src='img.png' onClick={this.test} />
    </div>
  }else{
    return null;
  }
},
render () {
  return (
    <span>
      <button onClick={this.onClick}>
        See Popup
      </button>
      {this.showPopup()}
    </span>
  );
}
```

Comment: Dont you have any error in console when clickkng or before clicking?

Comment: No errors when page loads or when clicking on the image. To test it, I made the this.state.isPopupVisible true, and the onClick worked. I just can't figure out why it doesn't work when it initially doesn't render.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, but...

```
onClickBody () {
  setTimeout(function(){
    if (!this.clickedInBounds && this.isMounted()) {
      this.setState({isPopupVisible: false});
      document.body.removeEventListener('click', this.onClickBody)
    }
    this.clickedInBounds = false;    
  }.bind(this), 0);
},
test () {
  console.log('the onClick from the image works!');
  this.clickedInBounds = true;
},
```

The setTimeout is just to make it run that code after `test` has a chance to run.  isMounted is just for the small chance that the component was unmounted between the click on body, and the setTimeout coming around.

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vulukefiti/3/edit?js,output)

Comment: Thanks so much for this, @FakeRainBrigand! It is a bit hacky but it's the only thing I've gotten to work so far. Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `onClickBody` handler is getting called before `test` is ever invoked, changing state and removing the image from the virtual DOM before the synthetic event ever fires.

There may be an elegant way around this, but because you are mixing native and React event APIs, my guess is that you'll have to change the signature of `onClickBody` to have the event as its first parameter and then wrap the body of the method in something like `if (e.target.nodeName !== "IMG") {}`.

JSFiddle showing this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding a `click` listener on `body`, you can add an underlying transparent div before rendering the popup that'll close the popup when clicked.

For example, this is how this is implemented in [react-bootstrap](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap) Modal component: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/Modal.jsx#L73

You can check out the demo here: http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a year for this Post but I know the right answer.

you have a lot of referencing dangers.

```
onClick () {
  var self = this;
  if(!this.state.isPopupVisible){
    self .setState({isPopupVisible: true});
    document.body.addEventListener('click', self .onClickBody)
  }
},
onClickBody () {
  var self = this;
  this.setState({isPopupVisible: false});
  document.body.removeEventListener('click', self .onClickBody)
},
test () {
  console.log('the onClick from the image works!');
},
showPopup () {
  var self = this;
  if(this.state.isPopupVisible){
    return <div>
      <img src='img.png' onClick={self.test} />
    </div>
  }else{
    return null;
  }
},
```

this should for sure solve your issue